# 2 Child views and one have Issue with AlignItems, the style also contains Row direction and wrapped

Tags: react-native

I have a strange issue with react native when checking on codesandbox.io(https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-water-3g6gp0?file=/src/App.js) the result looks fine but on the android simulator the AlignItems looks exactly like flex-start where I just want the items on the View with blue background to be centered vertically.

Here is the code below in case the link above doesn't work:

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const logoUri = `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3"><g fill="#61DAFB"><path d="M666.3 296.5c0-32.5-40.7-63.3-103.1-82.4 14.4-63.6 8-114.2-20.2-130.4-6.5-3.8-14.1-5.6-22.4-5.6v22.3c4.6 0 8.3.9 11.4 2.6 13.6 7.8 19.5 37.5 14.9 75.7-1.1 9.4-2.9 19.3-5.1 29.4-19.6-4.8-41-8.5-63.5-10.9-13.5-18.5-27.5-35.3-41.6-50 32.6-30.3 63.2-46.9 84-46.9V78c-27.5 0-63.5 19.6-99.9 53.6-36.4-33.8-72.4-53.2-99.9-53.2v22.3c20.7 0 51.4 16.5 84 46.6-14 14.7-28 31.4-41.3 49.9-22.6 2.4-44 6.1-63.6 11-2.3-10-4-19.7-5.2-29-4.7-38.2 1.1-67.9 14.6-75.8 3-1.8 6.9-2.6 11.5-2.6V78.5c-8.4 0-16 1.8-22.6 5.6-28.1 16.2-34.4 66.7-19.9 130.1-62.2 19.2-102.7 49.9-102.7 82.3 0 32.5 40.7 63.3 103.1 82.4-14.4 63.6-8 114.2 20.2 130.4 6.5 3.8 14.1 5.6 22.5 5.6 27.5 0 63.5-19.6 99.9-53.6 36.4 33.8 72.4 53.2 99.9 53.2 8.4 0 16-1.8 22.6-5.6 28.1-16.2 34.4-66.7 19.9-130.1 62-19.1 102.5-49.9 102.5-82.3zm-130.2-66.7c-3.7 12.9-8.3 26.2-13.5 39.5-4.1-8-8.4-16-13.1-24-4.6-8-9.5-15.8-14.4-23.4 14.2 2.1 27.9 4.7 41 7.9zm-45.8 106.5c-7.8 13.5-15.8 26.3-24.1 38.2-14.9 1.3-30 2-45.2 2-15.1 0-30.2-.7-45-1.9-8.3-11.9-16.4-24.6-24.2-38-7.6-13.1-14.5-26.4-20.8-39.8 6.2-13.4 13.2-26.8 20.7-39.9 7.8-13.5 15.8-26.3 24.1-38.2 14.9-1.3 30-2 45.2-2 15.1 0 30.2.7 45 1.9 8.3 11.9 16.4 24.6 24.2 38 7.6 13.1 14.5 26.4 20.8 39.8-6.3 13.4-13.2 26.8-20.7 39.9zm32.3-13c5.4 13.4 10 26.8 13.8 39.8-13.1 3.2-26.9 5.9-41.2 8 4.9-7.7 9.8-15.6 14.4-23.7 4.6-8 8.9-16.1 13-24.1zM421.2 430c-9.3-9.6-18.6-20.3-27.8-32 9 .4 18.2.7 27.5.7 9.4 0 18.7-.2 27.8-.7-9 11.7-18.3 22.4-27.5 32zm-74.4-58.9c-14.2-2.1-27.9-4.7-41-7.9 3.7-12.9 8.3-26.2 13.5-39.5 4.1 8 8.4 16 13.1 24 4.7 8 9.5 15.8 14.4 23.4zM420.7 163c9.3 9.6 18.6 20.3 27.8 32-9-.4-18.2-.7-27.5-.7-9.4 0-18.7.2-27.8.7 9-11.7 18.3-22.4 27.5-32zm-74 58.9c-4.9 7.7-9.8 15.6-14.4 23.7-4.6 8-8.9 16-13 24-5.4-13.4-10-26.8-13.8-39.8 13.1-3.1 26.9-5.8 41.2-7.9zm-90.5 125.2c-35.4-15.1-58.3-34.9-58.3-50.6 0-15.7 22.9-35.6 58.3-50.6 8.6-3.7 18-7 27.7-10.1 5.7 19.6 13.2 40 22.5 60.9-9.2 20.8-16.6 41.1-22.2 60.6-9.9-3.1-19.3-6.5-28-10.2zM310 490c-13.6-7.8-19.5-37.5-14.9-75.7 1.1-9.4 2.9-19.3 5.1-29.4 19.6 4.8 41 8.5 63.5 10.9 13.5 18.5 27.5 35.3 41.6 50-32.6 30.3-63.2 46.9-84 46.9-4.5-.1-8.3-1-11.3-2.7zm237.2-76.2c4.7 38.2-1.1 67.9-14.6 75.8-3 1.8-6.9 2.6-11.5 2.6-20.7 0-51.4-16.5-84-46.6 14-14.7 28-31.4 41.3-49.9 22.6-2.4 44-6.1 63.6-11 2.3 10.1 4.1 19.8 5.2 29.1zm38.5-66.7c-8.6 3.7-18 7-27.7 10.1-5.7-19.6-13.2-40-22.5-60.9 9.2-20.8 16.6-41.1 22.2-60.6 9.9 3.1 19.3 6.5 28.1 10.2 35.4 15.1 58.3 34.9 58.3 50.6-.1 15.7-23 35.6-58.4 50.6zM320.8 78.4z" /><circle cx="420.9" cy="296.5" r="45.7" /><path d="M520.5 78.1z" /></g></svg>`;

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={styles.div1}></View>
      <View style={styles.div2}>
        <Text>Some very very very very very very very very long text</Text>
        <Image
          accessibilityLabel="React logo"
          source={{ uri: logoUri }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.logo}
        />
        <Image
          accessibilityLabel="React logo"
          source={{ uri: logoUri }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.logo}
        />
        <Text>Some very very very very very very very very long text</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    minWidth: "100%",
    minHeight: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    maxWidth: "100%",
    maxHeight: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  div1: {
    minWidth: "50%",
    minHeight: "100%",
    width: "50%",
    height: "100%",
    maxWidth: "50%",
    maxHeight: "100%",
    padding: "1%",
    backgroundColor: "#f57",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
  },
  div2: {
    minWidth: "50%",
    minHeight: "100%",
    width: "50%",
    height: "100%",
    maxWidth: "50%",
    maxHeight: "100%",
    padding: "1%",
    backgroundColor: "#58f",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  logo: {
    height: 200,
    width: 200
  }
});

export default App;
```

Here is a screenshot inside the simulator :
[image]
Different images but here is a picture of the desired outcome on the simulator(similar to codesandbox) :
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My expo version is 5.4.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in your `div2` style it will align your content to `center`

```js
  div2: {
    minWidth: "50%",
    minHeight: "100%",
    width: "50%",
    height: "100%",
    maxWidth: "50%",
    maxHeight: "100%",
    padding: "1%",
    backgroundColor: "#58f",
    justifyContent:'space-evenly'
  },
```

then give above styling to `div2` and change `div2` `View` like this

Edit:

```js
<View style={styles.div2}>
    <Text>Some very very very very very very very very long text</Text>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
        <Image
          accessibilityLabel="React logo"
          source={{ uri: logoUri }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.logo}
        />
        <Image
          accessibilityLabel="React logo"
          source={{ uri: logoUri }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.logo}
        />
    </View>
    <Text>Some very very very very very very very very long text</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your answer will center the content horizontally not vertically

Comment: it will center vertically not horizontally. justifycontent is vertical alignment property but when you add flexDirection: 'row' horizontal becomes vertical and vertical becomes horizontal

check this it will work like this: https://imgur.com/a/V6orZSV

Comment: Ah I see what you did, but I need the flowDirection to be a row and it needs to wrap. In your example you will see that the Images are now not next to each other because it s not a row and doesn't wrap any more

Comment: I added a screenshot for the expected result

Comment: your desired output is not vertically alinged ```center``` it's ```space-evenly```

Comment: The edit doesn't work the text is now floating above the image on the simulator. My code works fine on codesandbox as is, space-evenly is not for alignItems but for justifyContent, justifyContent is for the mainAxis where as alignItems is for the secondary one. I understand why you want to get rid of the row, but making Images part of the Text component doesn't seem very nice as well.

Comment: For additional information changing alignItems to flex-start or flex-end doesn't change the end result at all.

Comment: try recent edit it will work like your expected result

Comment: I didn't test your recent edit, because I think it will works, but again you are not using alignItems. According to https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox alignItems should work my question is basically why it doesn't work. The example I pasted is not what I will use I am actually generating the code based on some rest api and just add the components Text, Images... one after the other there is currently no View Components, if I cannot find another solution I will probably have to do what you are doing but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I'll add a +1 to your answer because it works, even though it is not the outcome I would like to have

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct answer. There was no other answers. So I changed my code generation to allow child views.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also add `justifyContent: "center"` to the styles for div2? That should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. justifyContent: "center" will center the content horizontally, and this works fine on the device as well, my question is for the content to be centered vertically on the second div.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of how it appears on the android simulator?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that, the screenshot is with your change justifyContent